# How could Emperor Palpatine afford having such a massive fleet of Star Destroyers?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

How could Emperor Palpatine afford having such a massive fleet of Star Destroyers built on Exegol? One could theorize that it was done for free by The Sith Eternal (his fan club) but there's the price of the parts they need. Is there an in-universe explanation of the origin of such immense resources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is answered in *Star Wars The Rise of Skywalker The Visual Dictionary*, on the page about the Sith Star Destroyer we have a little Fact File window with the following point in it:

> The presence of Sith loyalists within the executive boards of Sienar-Jaemus and Kuat-Entralla allowed the clandestine funnelling of supplied and designs to Exegol through various intermediaries.

Sienar-Jaemus and Kuat-Entralla are both ship manufacturers and so we see that the fleet was funded and supplied largely through the support of high ups within the two companies.

Comment: Sadly undercutting the need for the two quests for Sith wayfinders that drive most of the plot...

Comment: @jeffronicus Not really, the Resistance was able to get to Exegol because they followed Rey's beacons/path. Presumably the Sith Eternal had a similar thing set up for their runners. Or simply there were other Wayfinders they used.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot All the fluff says there's only two of them. So presumably, the wayfinders simply aren't necessary. The Resistance could have hacked an existing beacon network or hijacked/followed a freighter or something.

Comment: @Harabeck That provides they know about that if it exists. The only way they knew to find it was through a Wayfinder so of course that's where their attention is. Presumably if they found other ways they would have pursued those as well.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I mean, they had to know the wayfinders existed too. I think the main thing is this: if there was regular shipping to exegol, why did a sith agent need a knife with a pull-out thingy to tell him where the wayfinder was hidden in wreckage? Surely he would just use the same method as the freighters.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It's not the Resistance showing up at the end; it's the fact that there's this giant logistics scheme running supplies to Exegol and Kylo needs to be handed a clue.